# Only serialize private properties with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm migrating an existing communication layer to use REST with JSON. The previous framework serialized all private fields and ignored public getters, I would like to accomplish the same with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

I would like to make as little changes on the model classes being transferred, so annotations are not an option.

I already found a solutions to serialize the private properties:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ...
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

But having this example POJO, the JSON string also contains the value of `getNoGetter()` which I don't want:

> "noGetter" : "another string"

```
public class PrivateObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public PrivateObject() {
    }

    public PrivateObject(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id+": "+name;
    }

    public String getNoGetter() {
        return "another string";
    }
}
```

Is there a way to configure [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to just consider the private fields?

Expected result of `new PrivateObject(1234, "test")`:

```
{
  "id" : 1234,
  "name" : "test",
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question, do you want to ignore a particular private field "noGetter" ?

Comment: getNoGetter() is a public method which is not actually a getter of a field but only returns a "generated" String see getNoGetter() in the class. I want to only serialize private fields and ignore all other methods.